# Placing date at bottom of page

Tags: titles

I want to place `\l_date_tl` at the bottom of the page, but currently it is getting printed just after the author.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_title_tl
\tl_new:N \l_author_tl
\tl_new:N \l_date_tl 

\keys_define:nn { pstn_keys }
  {
    title  .tl_set:N = \l_title_tl,
    author .tl_set:N = \l_author_tl,
    date   .tl_set:N = \l_date_tl,
   }

\NewDocumentCommand {\pstn} {m}
  {

    \keys_set:nn { pstn_keys } { #1 }

    \begin{titlepage}

      \par \vspace{\baselineskip}

      \centering

      { \LARGE\bfseries\boldmath \l_title_pstn_tl \par }

      \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}
      {
        \large\lineskip 0.5em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
          \l_author_pstn_tl
        \end{tabular}
        \par
      }
      \vspace{1em}

      \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
        { \large \l_date_pstn_tl }
      \end{tabular}

      \par \vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

    \end{titlepage}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pstn
  {
    title = {Test},
    author = {Heime Borgia},
    date = {2024},
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please try to make your questions self-contained.  Making everyone go through your previous questions because you didn't explain what's happening makes for a frustrating and difficult experience for your potential answerers.

Comment: What additional information would you require ?

Comment: The introductory sentence is helpful; thanks.  My next (unrelated) question is, do you understand the code that you've written?  It seems like your complaint relates to the `\vspace{1em}`.  Why do you have it in there, if that's not what you want?

Comment: Have done `\begin{tabular}[b]{c}  { \large \l_date_pstn_tl } \end{tabular}`. but it is not taking effect.

Comment: `\vspace{1em}` is introducing `1em` of space. If you want to fill all the remaining space use `\vspace{\stretch{1}}`.